# How to access a different subnet on local net

Tags: networking, ssh

[This is my setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRxVK.png)

I'm trying to SSH into a diferent subnet on my local net, I can SSH from PC 2 to PC 1 but not the other way around. router has DHCP enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure a firewall rule on the router to allow the ingress traffic. I suggest you configure port forwarding. You can follow this link[1] for a detailed guide.

[1] https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ssh-port-forwarding